# tikpicture moves location with every compilation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am using TikZ to draw arrows or position figures. My code has three slides. TikZ worked fine with the first two, but with the last, the image moves with every compilation. I suspect the reason is in the setting made in the first slides (`remember picture`). However I was not able to fix it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{xparse}%  For \NewDocumentCommand
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}
\begin{document}

% For every picture that defines or uses external nodes, you'll have to
% apply the 'remember picture' style. To avoid some typing, we'll apply
% the style to all pictures.
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{frame}{Polynomials}
\begin{itemize}
\item Many functions can be well described by a high-order
polynomial
\item MATLAB represents a polynomials by a vector of coefficients
\begin{itemize} \item if vector P describes a polynomial\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[help lines](-2,-1)grid(4,2); % shows background
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
%\node at (origin) {*};
\coordinate  (text1) at (1,1);
\node at (text1) {
$
\mytikzmark{B1}{a}\mytikzmark{B2}{x^3}+\mytikzmark{B3}{b}\mytikzmark{B4}{x^2}+\mytikzmark{B5}{c}\mytikzmark{B6}{x+}\mytikzmark{B7}{d}\mytikzmark{B8}{   }
$
};
\node [text width=1.0cm, anchor=east] at (0, 0) (P1) {\textcolor{blue}{P(1)}};
\draw[blue,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (P1) -- ($(B1)!0.5!(B2)$);

\node [text width=1.0cm, anchor=east] at (1, 0) (P2) {\textcolor{blue}{P(2)}};
\draw[blue,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (P2) -- ($(B3)!0.5!(B4)$);

\node [text width=1.0cm, anchor=east] at (2.5, 0) (P3) {\textcolor{blue}{P(3)}};
\draw[blue,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (P3) -- ($(B5)!0.5!(B6)$);

\node [text width=1.0cm, anchor=east] at (3.5, 0) (P4) {\textcolor{blue}{P(4)}};
\draw[blue,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (P4) -- ($(B7)!0.5!(B8)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\item P=[1 0 -2] represents the polynomial $x^2-2$
\item P=[2 0 0 0] represents the polynomial $2x^3$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Nonlinear Root Finding}
\begin{columns}[b]
\begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Many real-world problems require us to solve f(x)=0
\item Can use {\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{fzero}}} to calculate roots for any arbitrary function
\item {\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{fzero}}} needs a function passed to it.
\item We will see this more and more as we delve into solving
equations.
\item Make a separate function file
\newline
{\scriptsize{\fontseries{b}\texttt{
\textcolor{blue}{
>> x=fzero('myfun',1);\tikz[na] \coordinate (s-mat); \\
>> x=fzero(@myfun,1)}}}}
\begin{itemize} \item 1 specifies a
point close to where
you think the root is\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0pt}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (A) at ($(current page.south west)+(7.4cm,2.1cm)$)
{\includegraphics[width=5.4cm]{image2}};
\path (A) coordinate (mat);         
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{0pt}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path[->,black,thick] (s-mat) edge (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Anonymous Functions}
\begin{itemize}
\item You do not have to make a separate function file
\newline
{\scriptsize{\fontseries{b}\texttt{
\textcolor{blue}{
>> x=fzero(@myfun,1)}}}}
\begin{itemize}\item What if myfun is really simple?\end{itemize}
\item Instead, you can make an anonymous function
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines](-2,-1)grid(4,2); % shows background
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\node at (origin) {*};
\coordinate  (text1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (text2) at (2,2);
\node [text width=8.0cm] at (text1) {
{\scriptsize{\fontseries{b}\texttt{
\textcolor{blue}{
>> x=fzero(@\mytikzmark{B1}{(}x\mytikzmark{B2}{)}\textcolor{black}{$\underbrace{\text{\textcolor{blue}{\mytikzmark{B3}{(}cos(exp(x))+x\textasciicircum 2-1\mytikzmark{B4}{)}}}}$}, 1 );}}}}
};
\node  [text width=8.0cm]  at (text2) {
{\scriptsize{\fontseries{b}\texttt{
\textcolor{blue}{>> x=fminbnd(@(x) (cos(exp(x))+x\textasciicircum2-1),-1,2);}}}}
};
\node [text width=1.0cm, anchor=east] at (0, 0) (P1) {\textcolor{blue}{P(1)}};
\draw[blue,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (P1) -- ($(B1)!0.5!(B2)$);

\node [text width=1.0cm, anchor=east] at (1, 0) (P2) {\textcolor{blue}{P(2)}};
\draw[blue,-stealth, thick, shorten >= 0.5ex, shorten <= -0.5ex] (P2) -- ($(B3)!0.5!(B4)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

this is what i want to get for my last slide. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,arrows,shapes,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{xparse}%  For \NewDocumentCommand

% For every picture that defines or uses external nodes, you'll have to
% apply the 'remember picture' style. To avoid some typing, we'll apply
% the style to all pictures.
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={remember picture},
  na/.style={baseline=-.5ex},
  arrow/.style={-stealth}
}  

\newcommand\MyFont[1]{%
  {\scriptsize\bfseries\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Anonymous Functions}
\begin{itemize}
\item You do not have to make a separate function file

\MyFont{>> x=fzero(@myfun,1)}

  \begin{itemize}\item What if myfun is really simple?\end{itemize}
  \item Instead, you can make an anonymous function

  \MyFont{
    >> x=fzero(@(\tikzmark{B1}x)
    \tikzmark{B3}(cos(exp(x))+x\textasciicircum 2-1\tikzmark{B4}), 1 )}
    \vspace{0.8cm}

  \MyFont{>> x=fminbnd(@(x) (cos(exp(x))+x\textasciicircum2-1),-1,2);}
  \end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[arrow] 
  ( $ (pic cs:B1) + (-10pt,-0.3cm) $ ) node[below,font=\scriptsize] {input} -- 
  ( $ (pic cs:B1) + (0.4ex,-2pt) $ );
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=4pt}] 
  (pic cs:B3) -- (pic cs:B4) node[midway,below=9pt,font=\scriptsize] {function to evaluate};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- I made some modifications to your code. In particular, I simplified it defining a command to easily change font and removed superfluous elements.
- In your code you are misussing `\mytikzmark`; you defined it with one argument but you are using it as it had two: `\mytikzmark{B3}{(}`; this is incorrect and was producing a weird interaction between `\text` and `\mytikzmark`.
- Since you are already loading it, I'd suggest you to use the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library and let its `\tikzmark` command do the hard work for you, as I did in my example code.
- Looking at your code, it appears that you are also misusing `\mytikzmark` in another sense; the main idea for this command was to place some marks for elements and then use the marks in a `tikzpicture` *outside* where they were defined. You are placing the marks and using them in the same `tikzpicture`, so it's really an overkill (besides nesting `tikzpicture`s). In my code I separated the mark placement from its ussage.
- Apparently the text in blue represents code, so I'd suggest you to use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to facilitate writing it. The [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/prettifier) package could also be of interest for you.

Comment: In fact there is http://texdoc.net/pkg/matlab-prettifier from our Jubobs.

Comment: @percusse I don't use Matlab, so I didn't recognize it. Will add the info about this prettifier, thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Your code integrated well with my previous slides. the problem i am facing now is when i add new slides. In my new slides i follow the same procedure you described for tikz images. however, the previous slides would get messed up. is there anything that i should reset when reusing the code on a following slide?UPDATE: Problem got fixed when I used different names for my tikzmark. However, I don't want to keep track of the names I have used in different slides. Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: @MAS feel free to open a follow-up new question.